# Determine all solutions to $|x+12|+|x-5|=15$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Determine all solutions to the following.
$$ \lvert x+12\rvert +\lvert x-5\rvert =15.$$

How can I solve problems like this? Should I try graphing the function? Should I somehow consider various cases? Or should I square both sides and try to use identities like $|x-5|^2=(x-5)^2$?

Comment: please add where the problem is from, what you have tried, and preferably use LaTeX formatting.

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem?  I'd suggest considering various ranges on x to solve this with a "Divide and conquer" idea.

Comment: This question really reads like "Do my homework."

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you are just looking for real solutions. I see the real-analysis tag... So one way to do this would be to use the definition of absolute value. Recall that
$$
\lvert x\rvert = \begin{cases} x & \text{if } x\geq 0  \\ -x & \text{if } x< 0\end{cases}.
$$

1) Look for solution in $(-\infty, -12]$. Then you get
$$
-12 - x + 5 - x = 15 \Rightarrow x = -11\quad\text{not in the right interval}.
$$
So no solutions in the interval $(-\infty, -12]$.

2) Look for solutions in $(-12, 5]$. Then you get
$$
x + 12 + 5 - x = 15.
$$
No solution

3) Look for solutions in $(5, \infty)$. I will let you think about that one.

Comment: it should  be $-12-x$ in teh 1st case

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Thanks!

Comment: should we include the assumption that $x$ is real in the solution?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: That would probably be a good idea. I will leave my answer as is, but I will add that I assume we are just looking for real solutions. Your answer is better though.

Answer (score 4):

Draw a horizontal straight line, and call it the $x$-axis.  Put a dot at the origin.

Put a big dot at $-12$. Put another big dot at $5$. Note that the distance between the two dots is $17$.
If $x$ is any number, then $|x+12|=|x-(-12)|$ is the **distance** from $x$ to $-12$. Similarly, $|x-5|$ is the distance from $x$ to $5$.

Thus $|x+12|+|x-5|$ is the **sum** of the distances from $x$ to $-12$ and $5$.

This sum cannot be $15$, since $-12$ and $5$ are too far away from each other.

Comment: Your geometric explanation nicely illustrates (a special case of) [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality):
$||x+12|+|x-5||=||x+12|+|5-x|| \ge |(x+12)+(5-x)| = 17$.

Answer (score 3):

We know $|a+ib|=+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ where $a,b$ are real.

If we take $x$ to be real,

If $x<-12, -12-x+5-x=-7-2x=15\implies 2x=-22,x=-11$ which is impossible

If $-12\le x\le 5, x+12+(5-x)=17\ne 15$

If $x>5, x+12+x-5=15,2x=8,x=4$ which is impossible as $x>5$

---

If we allow complex values of $x,x=a+ib$(say) where $a,b$ are real.

So, $\sqrt{(a+12)^2+b^2}+\sqrt{(a-5)^2+b^2}=15$

As we know the locus of the points whose the sum of the distances from the two  foci $(-12,0);(5,0)$ are constant(the length of the major axis ), is ellipse.

Now, we can simplify to find the equation of the  ellipse.

Observe that the distance of the foci is $\sqrt{(-12-5)^2+(0-0)^2}=17>15=$ the length of the major axis.

So, there is no solution in real $(a,b)$

Comment: You don't even have to talk about ellipses... $|x - 5| \geq |Re(x) - 5|$ and $|x + 12| \geq |Re(x) + 12|$, so by the real case $|x - 5| + |x + 12| \geq 17$ for all complex $x$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very difficult to graph the functions of this type.

Notice that the graphs $y=|x-5|$ and $y=|x+12|$ can be obtained by shifting the graph of $y=|x|$ by 5 to the right/by 12 to the left.

WolframAlpha: [plot |x-5|,|x+12|](http://tinyurl.com/n6nowr3)

[image]

Now we want to draw the graph of the sum of these two functions.

- For $x\ge5$ both of them are linear functions with slope $1$. The sum will be linear function with slope $2$.
- For $-12\le x \le 5$ we add linear functions with slopes $1$ and $-1$, so their sum has slope $0$, i.e., it is a constant function.
- For $x\le-12$ we get a linear function with slope $-2$

(When graphing sum of two functions we simply at each $x$ need to add the heights given by the two graphs.)

WolframAlpha: [plot |x-5|,|x+12|,|x-5|+|x+12|](http://tinyurl.com/m39uzj5)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 different cases to check.

- $x+12\ge 0$ and $x-5\ge 0$
- $x+12\ge 0$ and $x-5 < 0$
- $x+12 < 0$ and $x-5\ge 0$
- $x+12 < 0$ and $x-5 < 0$

Now you can switch the values of $|x+12|$ and $|x-5|$ and solve for each case. It is evident at first that there will be at most $4$ solutions.

To switch the value remember the definition of the absolute value $|x|=\begin{cases} x & \text{, } x\geq 0  \\ -x & \text{, } x< 0\end{cases}$

So if you are checking $x+12<0$ then replace $|x+12|$ with $-x-12$.